# request body characters showing ? using fetch or request from quickbooks

Tags: node.js, express, fetch, quickbooks

I am using quickbooks api in a node 10.16 environment.
I am trying to get the PDF through the API.

I am getting what looks like the correct response but when I open it it shows blank

I have downloaded a file using postman directly and that file works.

I have opened both files up using notepad++ and I can see some characters on my file have ? or a square where on the postman file I see a character.

[This google folder has both files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11fl0JeuneNKzpc9yr607-P6rYtGKS0wq?usp=sharing)

This is the main code where I grab the information from the API using fetch

```
      return fetch(url, fetchOptions).then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.text()
        }
```

response.text() is where the bad decoding is happening because I have saved it directly to a file or tried decoding it with TextDecoder and it always gives me bad characters.

Here is what I have tested so far

```
            return response.arrayBuffer().then(buffer => {
              let decodedValue = new util.TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(buffer)
              fs.writeFile('decodetest.pdf', decodedValue, (err) => {
                // throws an error, you could also catch it here
                if (err) throw err;

                // success case, the file was saved
                console.log('decode file saved!');
              });
              return decodedValue;
            });
```

rp below is using a different package response-promise.  Also giving the same results.

```
      return rp(options)
          .then(function (response) {
              console.log("Did a new response");
              response.body
              fs.writeFile('requesttest.pdf', response.body, (err) => {
                // throws an error, you could also catch it here
                if (err) throw err;

                // success case, the file was saved
                console.log('request test file saved!');
              });
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
              // Delete failed...
          });
```

Comment: Do you just want to download the file from the browser, or display it in the browser?

Comment: This is getting a pdf file from quickbooks.  Even just saving the file on the server it still is broken due to bad characters.

Comment: What happens if you write the bytes out to a file without decoding? Seems a bit strange to me that the API would encode the PDF file's bytes as UTF8 instead of giving you the  raw bytes directly.